# controlling order of variables in an expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, how do you change the order of importance of variables? for example: if i enter b+c+a+d, i get a+b+c+d but i want  b and d to preceed other variables. so that i get b+d+a+c

note, i'd like to use it where + is non-commutative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to define an ordering function like:

```
In[1]:= CPOrdering[a]=3;
CPOrdering[b]=1;
CPOrdering[d]=2;
CPOrdering[c]=4;
```

Although, for more complicated examples, you should probably be smarter about it than this - ie use pattern matching.

Then you can sort expressions using

```
In[5]:= CirclePlus[a,b,c,d]
SortBy[%,CPOrdering]
Out[5]= a\[CirclePlus]b\[CirclePlus]c\[CirclePlus]d
Out[6]= b\[CirclePlus]d\[CirclePlus]a\[CirclePlus]c
```

This can then be automated using something like

```
CPOrdering[a_, b_] := CPOrdering[a] < CPOrdering[b]
CirclePlus[a__] /; (!OrderedQ[{a}, CPOrdering]) := CirclePlus@@SortBy[{a}, CPOrdering]
```

Answer (score 3):

The underlying reason `b+c+a+d` becomes `a+b+c+d` in Mathematica is because `Plus` has the attribute `Orderless`. In general, a symbol `f` with attribute `Orderless`  means that the elements of `f` in an expession `f[e1, e2, e3]`, the elements `ei` should be sorted into canonical order, and in particular, Mathematica's canonical order equivalent to that of `OrderedQ` and `Ordering`.

`Orderless` is even accounted for during pattern matching:

```
In[47]:= a+b+c+d /. a+c -> e
Out[47]= b+d+e
```

It's highly, highly recommended that you do NOT remove the `Orderless` attribute from `Plus` because the consequences could be dire for lots of functionality in Mathematica.

As other posters have noted, your best bet is to simply define your own function that is NOT `Orderless`, and will therefore preserve argument order. You might also find `HoldForm` useful in very limited circumstances.

Also note that nothing stops you from typesetting symbols in an expression in whatever order you want in a notebook, as long as you don't evaluate-in-place, etc.

Answer (score 2):

So, don't use "+", because Plus[] **IS** commutative.

Define your own myPlus[x_,y_]:= .... whatever.

If you have an idea of what your new Plus[] should do, post it and we may try to help you with the definition/

HTH!

PS> You may change the definition of Plus[] ... but :)

Comment: Probably best if you use something like CirclePlus - because it already has nice infix notation assigned to it.