# Preventing "Plus" from rearranging things

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following code creates a diagram of a certain calculation. My problem is that even though the terms in denominator are in a nice order, after applying Plus on it, they get rearranged arbitrarily. Any suggestions how to force the original order to be kept?

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/ind-sets-grid.png))</sub>

```
r[i_] := Floor[(i - 1)/n] + 1;
c[i_] := Mod[i, n, 1];
adj[a_, b_] := Abs[r[a] - r[b]] + Abs[c[a] - c[b]] == 1;
indsetQ[s_] := Not[Or @@ (adj @@@ Subsets[s, {2}])];
indsets[k_] := Select[Subsets[Range[n^2], {k}], indsetQ];
twoColorGraph[g_, seen_, lbl_] := Module[{radius = .22},
   vcoords = # -> {c[#], n - r[#]} & /@ Range[n^2];
   fv = Function[{p, v}, {EdgeForm[Thick], 
      If[MemberQ[seen, v], Pink, White], Disk[p, radius]}];
   GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True, VertexRenderingFunction -> fv,
     PlotLabel -> Style[lbl, 20], LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold], 
    VertexCoordinateRules -> vcoords, ImageSize -> 80]
   ];
n = 2;
g = Array[Boole[adj[#1, #2]] &, {n^2, n^2}];
weight[set_] := Times @@ (Subscript[\[Lambda], c[#], r[#]] & /@ set);
denominator = 
  twoColorGraph[g, #, weight[#]] & /@ 
   Join @@ (indsets[#] & /@ Range[2]);
numerator = twoColorGraph[g, {1}, weight[{1}]];
Style[numerator/(Plus @@ denominator), FontSize -> 30]
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, in intent, if not form, of another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947071/controlling-order-of-variables-in-an-expression).  Otherwise, I'd give you a +1 for the graphics alone.  What is the calculation for?

Comment: Yes, that's similar. The suggestion there is to define own function that's not orderless like "myPlus", but how do I get it to render the same as "Plus"?

Comment: The calculation is to find per-site occupation probabilities of hard-core repulsive local gas on a finite grid (ie, grand canonical gas with hard-core self-repulsion and hard-core pair interaction)

Comment: Seconded on the nice graphics. I answered the formatting question below =)

Comment: +1, @Yaroslav Bulatov, you're right.  It's definitely related, but not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick to formatting something like `myPlus` to **look** like `Plus` on output is to use `Format`. Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
Format[myPlus[expr__]] := Row[Riffle[{expr}, "+"]]
```

Then, what you will see visually in the notebook is:

```
In[7]:= x = myPlus[3, 2, 1]
Out[7]= 3+2+1
```

... but `x` will still have head `myPlus`.

Here is a [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningOutputFormats.html) from the documentation that goes into more details about formatting output, operator precedence, etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1, I was trying to do that with `Notation` and it was failing miserably.  I forgot to look at `Format` directly.

Comment: I tried to incorporate `Interpretation` with your answer so that it can be copied and pasted properly, but ran into problems. See the SO question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112299/421225