# Executing code in v.5.2 kernel from within v.7.01 session through MathLink

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I have *Mathematica* 7.01 and *Mathematica* 5.2 installed on the same machine. I wish to be able to evaluate code in the v.5.2 kernel from within *Mathematica* 7.01 session. I mean that running *Mathematica* 7.0.1 standard session I wish to have a command like `kernel5Evaluate` to evaluate some code in the 5.2 kernel and return the result into the 7.01 kernel and linked 7.01 FrontEnd notebook in such a way as this code would be executed in the 7.01 kernel.

For example (in the standard *Mathematica* v.7.01 session):

```
In[1]:= solutionFrom5 = kernel5Evaluate[NDSolve[{(y^\[Prime])[x]==y[x],y[1]==2},y,{x,0,3}]]
Out[1]= {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 3.}}, <>]}}

In[2]:= kernel5Evaluate[Plot3D[Sin[x y],{x,-Pi,Pi},{y,-Pi,Pi}]]
During evaluation of In[2]:= GraphicsData["PostScript", "\<\............
Out[2]= -SurfaceGraphics-
```

In the both cases the result should be as if the v.5.2 kernel is set to be "Notebook's Kernel" in the v.7.01 FrontEnd. And of course `solutionFrom5` variable should be set to the real solution returned by v.5.2 kernel.

Comment: What you want is `RunThrough`, but it refuses to play nice with me...

Comment: @Simon I'm looking for a `MathLink`-solution. I wish to use v.5.2 kernel multiple times through `kernel5Evaluate` per session.

Comment: I've never used `MathLink` before - but have been playing with it just now. It isn't as straightforward as I hoped it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working implementation of what I wanted. I have added checking for a dead `MathLink` connection as suggested by Todd Gayley [`here`](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2000/May/msg00383.html). Now `kernel5Evaluate` works reliable even if the slave kernel was terminated in unusual way. I also have much improved parsing of `Message`s and added some diagnostic messages for `kernel5Evaluate`. Here is the code:

```
$kern5Path = "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\5.2\\MathKernel.exe";

Clear[printMessage, printPrint, printPostScript]
printMessage[str_String] := 
  CellPrint@
   Cell[BoxData[
     RowBox[StringSplit[str, 
        x : ("MyDelimeterStart" | "MyDelimeterEnd") :> x] //. {x___, 
         "MyDelimeterStart", y_, "MyDelimeterEnd", z___} :> {x, 
         ToExpression[y], z}]], "Message", 
    CellLabel -> "(Kernel 5.2)", ShowCellLabel -> True];
printPostScript = 
  CellPrint@
    Cell[GraphicsData["PostScript", #], "Graphics", 
     CellLabel -> "(Kernel 5.2 PostScript)", ShowCellLabel -> True] &;
printPrint[str_String] := 
  CellPrint@
   Cell[If[StringTake[str, -1] === "\n", StringDrop[str, -1], str], 
    "Print", CellLabel -> "(Kernel 5.2 print, text mode)", 
    ShowCellLabel -> True];

Clear[linkEvaluate]
SetAttributes[linkEvaluate, HoldAllComplete]
linkEvaluate[link_LinkObject, expr_] := Catch[
   Module[{out = {}, postScript = {}, packet, result = Null},
    If[LinkReadyQ[link], 
     While[LinkReadyQ[link], 
      Print["Rest of the buffer:\t", 
       packet = LinkRead[link, Hold]]];
     If[Not@MatchQ[packet, Hold[InputNamePacket[_]]], 
      Message[kernel5Evaluate::linkIsBusy]; Throw[$Failed]]];
    LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[expr]]];
    While[
     Check[Not@
       MatchQ[packet = LinkRead[link, Hold], 
        Hold[InputNamePacket[_]]], 
      Message[kernel5Evaluate::linkIsClosed]; Throw[$Failed]],
     Switch[packet,
      Hold@DisplayPacket[_String], 
      AppendTo[postScript, First@First@packet],
      Hold@DisplayEndPacket[_String], 
      AppendTo[postScript, First@First@packet]; 
      printPostScript@StringJoin[postScript]; postScript = {},
      Hold@MessagePacket[__], ,
      Hold@TextPacket[_String], 
      If[StringMatchQ[First@First@packet, 
        WordCharacter .. ~~ "::" ~~ WordCharacter .. ~~ ": " ~~ __], 
       printMessage[First@First@packet], 
       printPrint[First@First@packet]],
      Hold@OutputNamePacket[_], ,
      Hold@ReturnExpressionPacket[_], result = First[First[packet]],
      _, AppendTo[out, packet]
      ]
     ];
    If[Length[out] > 0, Print["Unparsed packets: ", out]];
    result
    ]];
Clear[kernel5Evaluate]
SetAttributes[kernel5Evaluate, HoldAllComplete]
kernel5Evaluate::usage = "kernel5Evaluate[\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"expr\",\nFontFamily->\"Times New Roman\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)] writes \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"expr\",\nFontFamily->\"Times New Roman\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) to MathKernel 5.2, returns output and prints \
messages generated during computation.";
kernel5Evaluate::linkIsBusy = 
  "Kernel 5.2 is still running previous calculation.";
kernel5Evaluate::linkIsClosed = "Connection to Kernel 5.2 is lost.";
kernel5Evaluate::kernel5NotFound = 
  "Path `1` not found. Please set variable $kern5Path to correct path \
to MathKernel 5.2.";
kernel5Evaluate[expr_] :=
 If[TrueQ[MemberQ[Links[], $kern5]],
  If[LinkReadyQ[$kern5]; First[LinkError[$kern5]] == 0, 
   With[{$kern5 = $kern5}, linkEvaluate[$kern5, expr]], 
   LinkClose[$kern5]; kernel5Evaluate[expr]],
  Clear[$kern5];
  If[FileExistsQ[$kern5Path],
   $kern5 = LinkLaunch[$kern5Path <> " -mathlink -noinit"]; 
   LinkRead[$kern5]; LinkWrite[$kern5,
    Unevaluated[
     EnterExpressionPacket[$MessagePrePrint = ("MyDelimeterStart" <> 
          ToString[ToBoxes[#]] <> "MyDelimeterEnd") &; 
      SetOptions[$Output, {PageWidth -> Infinity}];]]]; 
   LinkRead[$kern5]; kernel5Evaluate[expr], 
   Message[kernel5Evaluate::kernel5NotFound, $kern5Path]; $Failed]
  ]
```

And here are some test expressions:

```
kernel5Evaluate[Unevaluated[2 + 2]]
kernel5Evaluate[$Version]
kernel5Evaluate[Quit[]]
kernel5Evaluate[Print["some string"];]
kernel5Evaluate[Sin[1,]]
kernel5Evaluate[1/0]

kernel5Evaluate[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]}] // 
 DeleteCases[#, HoldPattern[DefaultFont :> $DefaultFont], Infinity] &

kernel5Evaluate[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]];
ListPlot3D[First@%, Mesh -> Full, DataRange -> MeshRange /. Last[%]]

s = kernel5Evaluate[
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]]
% // InputForm // Short

kernel5Evaluate[ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]];
ListContourPlot[First@%, DataRange -> MeshRange /. Last[%], 
 Contours -> 10, 
 Method -> {"Refinement" -> {"CellDecomposition" -> "Quad"}}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an implementation based on Simon's code. It still requires improvement. The one unclear thing to me is how to handle Messages generated in the slave (v.5.2) kernel.

Here is my code:

```
Clear[linkEvaluate]
SetAttributes[linkEvaluate, HoldRest]
linkEvaluate[link_LinkObject, expr_] := Catch[
   Module[{out = {}, postScript = {}, packet, outputs = {}},
    While[LinkReadyQ[link], 
     Print["From the buffer:\t", LinkRead[link]]];
    LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[expr]]];
    While[Not@MatchQ[packet = LinkRead[link], InputNamePacket[_]],
     Switch[packet,
      DisplayPacket[_], AppendTo[postScript, First@packet],
      DisplayEndPacket[_], AppendTo[postScript, First@packet]; 
      CellPrint@
         Cell[GraphicsData["PostScript", #], "Output", 
          CellLabel -> "Kernel 5.2 PostScript ="] &@
       StringJoin[postScript]; postScript = {},
      TextPacket[_], 
      If[StringMatchQ[First@packet, 
        WordCharacter .. ~~ "::" ~~ WordCharacter .. ~~ ": " ~~ __], 
       CellPrint@
        Cell[BoxData@
          RowBox[{StyleBox["Kernel 5.2 Message = ", 
             FontColor -> Blue], First@packet}], "Message"], 
       CellPrint@
        Cell[First@packet, "Output", CellLabel -> "Kernel 5.2 Print"]],
      OutputNamePacket[_], AppendTo[outputs, First@packet];,
      ReturnExpressionPacket[_], AppendTo[outputs, First@packet];,
      _, AppendTo[out, packet]
      ]
     ];
    If[Length[out] > 0, Print[out]];
    Which[
     (l = Length[outputs]) == 0, Null,
     l == 2, Last@outputs,
     True, multipleOutput[outputs]
     ]
    ]];
Clear[kernel5Evaluate]
SetAttributes[kernel5Evaluate, HoldAll]
kernel5Evaluate[expr_] := 
 If[TrueQ[MemberQ[Links[], $kern5]], linkEvaluate[$kern5, expr], 
  Clear[$kern5]; $kern5 = LinkLaunch[
    "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\5.2\\MathKernel.exe -mathlink"]; 
  LinkRead[$kern5]; 
  LinkWrite[$kern5, 
   Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[$MessagePrePrint = InputForm;]]];
   LinkRead[$kern5]; kernel5Evaluate[expr]]
```

Here are test expressions:

```
plot = kernel5Evaluate[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]]
plot = kernel5Evaluate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]; Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]] // 
  DeleteCases[#, HoldPattern[DefaultFont :> $DefaultFont], Infinity] &
s = kernel5Evaluate[
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]]
s // InputForm // Short
kernel5Evaluate[1/0; Print["s"];]
```

It seems to work as expected. However it could be better...

Comment: These types of things are always a little messy - but you're right, it does seem to work ok. +1

Comment: @Simon I wonder is there a way to handle `Messages` more correctly? I'm forced to evaluate in the slave kernel `$MessagePrePrint = InputForm;` but I don't know how to expand `HoldForm` s in the generated strings. Try for example `kernel5Evaluate[1/0;]`.

Comment: I have opened a [separate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998561/mathlink-correct-handling-of-messages-generated-by-slave-kernel) question on this.

Comment: Cool. Sorry I didn't reply, just a tad overrun with work at the moment!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt at what you want,

First I define `linkEvaluate` that takes an active `Link` and passes it an expression.
If there's things for `LinkRead` still to read, then it reads them until there are no more.
Then it writes the expression and waits for the results to come back.
Then it reads the output until there's nothing left to read.
Normally, it then returns the first `ReturnExpressionPacket` unless you have set the final, optional argument, `all`, to `True` - in which case it returns everything it read.

```
Clear[linkEvaluate]
SetAttributes[linkEvaluate, HoldRest]
linkEvaluate[link_LinkObject, expr_, all : (True | False) : False] := 
  Catch[Module[{out = {}},
    While[LinkReadyQ[link], PrintTemporary[LinkRead[link]]];
    If[LinkReadyQ[link], Throw["huh"]];
    LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[expr]]];
    While[! LinkReadyQ[link], Pause[.1]];
    While[LinkReadyQ[link], AppendTo[out, LinkRead[link]]];
    If[all, out, Cases[out, _ReturnExpressionPacket][[1, 1]]]
    ]];
```

Then `kernel5Evaluate` first checks if the global `$kern5` is defined as a `LinkObject`, if not then it defines it. It then simply passes the work over to `linkEvaluate`.
You will have to replace "math5" with the filename and path of your Mma 5.2 kernel.

```
Clear[kernel5Evaluate]
SetAttributes[kernel5Evaluate, HoldAll]
kernel5Evaluate[expr_, all:(True|False):False] := If[TrueQ[MemberQ[Links[], $kern5]], 
  linkEvaluate[$kern5, expr, all], 
  Clear[$kern5]; $kern5 = LinkLaunch["math5 -mathlink"]; kernel5Evaluate[expr,all]
  ]
```

Comment: There is a trouble with getting such things as `InterpolatingFuntion` object. I'm forced to use `InputForm` inside `kernel5Evaluate` but the output is very large: `kernel5Evaluate[
 InputForm@
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]]`

Comment: @Alexey - I tested it with 7 and 8. Using 7 from within 8 is ok, but the other way around breaks. The docs say that `InterpolatingFunction` last changed in v3... so I don't know why it's not passing properly. Also, I didn't need `InputForm` to get it working when it did work.

Comment: @Alexey - Try just passing the `Plot` - that worked for me even when `NDSolve` failed. `Plot[Evaluate[
  y[x] /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
    y, {x, 0, 30}]], {x, 0, 30}]`

Comment: @Alexey - Maybe ask the WRI support crew about it. I think that it must be a problem of different data structures in the different versions. Since my code works fine when calling a kernel of the same version, I don't believe that the problem is on my end.

Comment: @Simon It seems that the problem has disappeared... Have a look on my [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983301/executing-code-in-v-5-2-kernel-from-within-v-7-01-session-through-mathlink/4992265#4992265), please. I'm trying to parse all types of packets returned by the slave (v.5.2) kernel.

Comment: @Alexey - I wonder what made the problem disappear... It's not obvious from your code.

Comment: @Simon It seems that the problem was incidental. The key decision was to use `While[Not@MatchQ[packet = LinkRead[link], InputNamePacket[_]],...`