# Mathematica not interpreting CenterDot as Times in numerical calculations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why doesn't Mathematica show the numerical result of

```
(0.8\[CenterDot]452\[CenterDot]20+1.5\[CenterDot]4180\[CenterDot]10
  -2\[CenterDot]900\[CenterDot]100) / (0.8\[CenterDot]452
  +1.5\[CenterDot]4180-1\[CenterDot]2\[CenterDot]900) // N
```

Comment: This is is a strange question. What made you think [`CenterDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CenterDot.html) would be interpreted as [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Times.html), when the documentation says that [`CenterDot` has no built-in meaning](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CenterDot.html#NSG)?

Comment: @Simon On the contrary: in a large part of the world, the centred dot is *the* standard multiplication sign (we abandoned × by the end of primary school).  Many users come to Mathematica "as a program that does math", not as a programming language.  Finally, there are so many easy ways to enter ∙ , e.g. palettes, the math-aware handwriting input of Windows 7, etc.)  Would you look up × if you hand-write 2×3 and the system accepts it?

Comment: @Simon You can also define CenterDot as the default multiplication character in the settings, which I thought also meant it could be used in calculation.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Tyilo: Both good points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to complete some of the other answers/comments, if you want `CenterDot` to be interpreted as `Times` in both input and output by using something like

```
Unprotect[CenterDot, Times];
CenterDot = Times;
Times /: MakeBoxes[Times[a__], fmt_] := 
  With[{cbox = ToBoxes[HoldForm[CenterDot[a]]]}, 
   InterpretationBox[cbox, Times[a]]];
Protect[CenterDot, Times];
```

Which you can add to your [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html) if you want it loaded by default.

This works on both numeric and symbolic expressions, e.g.

```
In[5]:= 1\[CenterDot]2\[CenterDot]3   
Out[5]= 6

In[6]:= a b c    
Out[6]= a\[CenterDot]b\[CenterDot]c
```

You can also make the automatically inserted multiplication symbol between space separated numbers be `CenterDot` by executing

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  {AutoMultiplicationSymbol -> True, NumberMultiplier -> "\[CenterDot]"}]
```

or by selecting **Center Dot** in the preferences dialog under **Appearance > Numbers > Multiplication**.

For example:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Simon, remind me, what is the reason to use MakesBoxes rather than Format?  (I seem to recall this being an issue, but I cannot remember why.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: That would be this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112299/421225

Comment: [Here's a different version of the `MakeBoxes` code](http://pastebin.com/Kij4Uk3M) that uses `TemplateBox` instead of `InterpretationBox`. This way you can edit the terms in a `\[CenterDot]` multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace `\[CenterDot]` by a space

Comment: Is there anyway to use `\[CenterDot]` as multiplication?

Comment: @Tyilo Yes, you can define `CenterDot = Times` to interpret (but not display) it as multiplication.  But I'd recommend getting a bit more familiar with Mathematica before making changes like this.  The reason this definition works will be clear if you evaluate `FullForm[a\[CenterDot]b]` (i.e. it's not because of the name of `\[CenterDot]`)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Actually, how would you go about making `\[CenterDot]` not be interpreted as `CenterDot`? Or any similar infix operator?

Comment: @Simon I don't know, I never played much with redefining notations

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication in Mathematica is written either as a space (`Times[a,b] == a b`) or as an asterisk (`Times[a,b] == a*b`).  `\[CenterDot]` is not interpreted as multiplication.

Comment: That's auto-inserted by the FE when you type a space between two numbers.

Comment: Let us not forget `a~Times~b`

Comment: Actually, I prefer `a~(#1\[Times]#2&)~b`

Comment: gosh~I~love~this~place! --> FullForm = Factorial[this[Complex[0, 1][gosh, love], place]] (I was mildly surprised; this serves to show the dark side of infix abuse...)

Comment: Szabolcs, you stated "Multiplication in Mathematica is written either as:" and gave two options.  I argue that `\[Times]` is in fact a third.

Answer (score 1):

I think Simon's first method can be written more concisely.  Please review:

```
Unprotect[Times];

CenterDot = Times;

Format[a_*b__] := Interpretation[HoldForm[a\[CenterDot]b], a*b];
```

---

Second attempt.  I believe this works properly with `Convert To > StandardForm` and editing.

```
CenterDot = Times;

MakeBoxes[Times[x__], _] := RowBox @ Riffle[ToBoxes /@ {x}, "\[CenterDot]"]
```

Comment: +1 For not protecting `Times` at the end! Also, `Format` isn't quite as stable as `MakeBoxes`, to quote Michael Pilat: ["`Format` isn't really intended to produce output that can be re-used as input, but just to format output."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4119830/421225)

Comment: @Simon general caveats regarding `Format` remaining, can you show me a way in which this fails?

Comment: @Simon Pardon me, I failed to read the linked question before asking.  I see the failure with Ctrl+Shift+N.

Comment: Type `a*b` into a input cell, then press `Ctrl-Shift-N` to convert it to standard form. This calls the `Format` rule and somehow gets stuck in a loop. If you find a work around for this, you can get a shiny green tick in my old question! (Edit: I guess I took too long to write this comment!)

Comment: @Simon, further experimentation shows that I cannot properly edit the output produced from `a b c` using the `MakeBoxes` method.  Do you experience this?  (I should say this affects *both* methods; I am wondering if there is a way around it.)

Comment: I guess it is a characteristic of `InterpretationBox` that I didn't notice before.

Comment: Normally I just convert to InputForm, edit and convert back. However, here's some different code that allows editing: `Times /: MakeBoxes[Times[a__], fmt_] := 
  With[{cbox = Block[{CenterDot}, ToBoxes[CenterDot[a]]]}, 
   InterpretationBox[cbox, Times[a], Editable -> True]];` problem is that it only changes what is seen, not what it's interpreted as.

Comment: What you need to do is to make a `TemplateBox` box object, like the built-in `TraditionalForms` or things made by the `Notation` package. Problem is, I'm not sure how to do this manually...

Comment: @Simon, please review my second attempt.

Comment: Actually, I think the following works (can you check it for me?): ``Unprotect[CenterDot, Times];
ClearAll[CenterDot, Times]
CenterDot = Times;
Times /: MakeBoxes[Times[a__], fmt_] := 
  With[{slots = Array[Slot, Length[{a}]], 
    rslots = Riffle[Array[Slot, Length[{a}]], "\[CenterDot]"],
    boxes = ToBoxes /@ {a}},
   TemplateBox[boxes, "CenterDot",
    DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[rslots] &),
    InterpretationFunction -> (RowBox[slots] &),
    Editable -> True, Selectable -> True]];
Protect[CenterDot, Times];``

Comment: Your 2nd attempt does work. But I feel it's kind of cheating! `Times` goes to `CenterDot` goes to `Times` goes to....

Comment: @Simon that seems to work better, but it doesn't edit as well as the simple form I added above.  I am not grasping the need for all the complexity (TemplateBox etc.).  Re: 2nd, cheating or not, can you force it into a recursion?

Comment: No I can't force a recursion, but "Convert To InputForm" (Ctrl-Shift-I) does not yield multiplication with a `*` like it should...

Comment: @Simon reflecting on this specific indented use, I don't think it is desirable for CenterDot to be converted to `*` in InputForm, but it is very good to know how to do what you demonstrate.  (Perhaps for this case ExportAutoReplacements would be good.)