# Overriding the default display order of orderless functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In two recent questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947071/controlling-order-of-variables-in-an-expression), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109306/preventing-plus-from-rearranging-things)), the previous posters were attempting to control the output order of `Plus`, which is an `Orderless` function.  Michael Pilat [indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947071/controlling-order-of-variables-in-an-expression/3954950#3954950) that, internally, `Orderless` functions `Sort` their parameters which was causing the difficulty.  However, he cautioned against making `Plus` non-`Orderless`.  The solutions to the two previous questions amount to creating a function that displays like `Plus` but is not `Orderless` itself.  This is certainly effective, but my question is how can we change the default `Sort` order?

Comment: Tricky... The functions `Order`, `OrderedQ`, `Sort` and the attribute `Orderless` all seem to be making separate calls to Mma's *canonical ordering* function. I tried redefining each one of these for the integers and none affected the other. Which is strange considering the documentation says "Ordering[list] gives the positions in list at which each successive element of Sort[list] appears." but changing `Sort` had no effect on `Ordering`.  I'm sure if it's possible to change the ordering used by `Orderless` functions.

Comment: Also, the `Sort` docs say "Sort[list,p] applies the function p to pairs of elements in list to determine whether they are in order. The default function p is OrderedQ[{#1,#2}]&" but changing `OrderedQ` for the integers has no effect on `Sort`.

Answer (score 5):

I need to do a little more research, but here's two ways; The catch is, you don't actually use the `Orderless` attribute. Simon should get half-credit for the technique of using pattern-matching with a condition from [his answer to question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947071/controlling-order-of-variables-in-an-expression/3948995#3948995) you referenced.

Messing with `Order`, `OrderedQ` and `Sort` won't get you anywhere, because `Orderless` functions sort with *equivalence* to those methods, but does not actually sort *with* them.

The first method, from Simon's answer, is to use a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html):

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[f, g]

In[2]:= f[stuff__] /; ! OrderedQ[{stuff}, Greater] := 
           f[Sequence@@Sort[{stuff}, Greater]]

In[3]:= f[1, 2, 3]
Out[3]= f[3, 2, 1]

In[4]:= f[3, 2, 1]
Out[4]= f[3, 2, 1]
```

That definition of f[stuff__] is evaluated if the order of the arguments is not the order desired, and then transformed into that order.

Another technique is to get a little more low-level and use [`$Pre`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Pre.html) or [`$PreRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24PreRead.html):

```
In[5]:= $Pre = 
 Function[{expr}, 
  expr /. g[stuff__] :> g[Sequence @@ Sort[{stuff}, Greater]]];

In[6]:= g[1, 2, 3]
Out[6]= g[3, 2, 1]

In[7]:= g[3, 2, 1]
Out[7]= g[3, 2, 1]
```

There are some issues with both of these approaches as they stand, for example, that particular `$Pre` function doesn't play well with e.g. `HoldForm[g[1,2,3]]`.

So, that's something to play with for now. I hope to update after I do a little more research into this.

Comment: Nice. I never thought of doing the sorting with `$Pre`/`$PreRead`. But as you said, this doesn't solve the original question of changing the sort order for an Orderless function. Note that Orderless is highly optimised and is a heap faster than the Conditional sorting definition used here.

Comment: Right, but keep in mind that `Orderless` implies that order of the elements doesn't matter, but the fact that you want to sort them in a non-standard way implies that it does, so why use `Orderless`? I think we're left finding the best possible way to transparently sort arguments in an ordered expression. Besides sorting, `Orderless` has other semantic meaning in expressions under various circumstances, like pattern-matching.

Comment: your question of why choose `Orderless` when we wish to have a specific sorting order I think misses the point. You are correct in that order is somewhat important, but it is more for aesthetics rather than having any bearing on how Mathematica comprehends the functions themselves. As I understand it, the arguments are sorted to create an `Orderless` system from an ordered one. To me, this implies that any sort order is valid, as long as it is consistent. Since, the choice of sort order is arbitrary by virtue of the function being orderless, why can't we use one that we specify?

Comment: any additional thoughts on this?