# Patterns with Orderless subexpressions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to deal with patterns like `f[{a,b}]=...` where `a` and `b` are supposed to be orderless

So far I've implemented this by using default `Sort[]` on subexpressions every time `f` is defined or evaluated.

My questions are

1. Is this as robust as `Orderless`?
2. Is there a better way?

PS: An example application is tree decomposition where you recursively build up quantities like subtree[bag1->bag2] where bag1 and bag2 are orderless sets of vertices

**answer update**

Michael Pilat's answer shows how to define a rule to automatically sort f's subexpressions. Alternative solution is to define a custom head like `Bag` with Orderless attribute and use that head for any orderless sublists

Comment: It's not clear to me why you don't use Orderless ...

Comment: Apply Orderless to which Head? I need a and b to be orderless, which I represent as lists right now. If I apply "Orderless" to head List, that will make *all* lists orderless, not really what I want

Comment: Sorry, but I get confused because orderless means commutativity, and pattern matching uses this to get matches that an ordered entity could not match. (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FlatAndOrderlessFunctions.html) I don't understand how you get that with Sort[].

Comment: I just try to keep "a" and "b" sorted all the time. So for instance, if I need to modify value of f[{{1,2,3},{5,4,3}], I would first sort {5,4,3} into {3,4,5} and modify value of f[{{1,2,3},{3,4,5}}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I answered [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4111778/272923) I consulted with a few colleagues who agreed that the following is indeed the best / typical way to handle this problem:

```
f[{a_, b_}] := 
 f[{Sort[a], Sort[b]}] /; Not[OrderedQ[a]] || Not[OrderedQ[b]]

In[99]:= f[{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 3}}]

Out[99]= f[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}]
```

Alternately, you could replace the inner `List` heads with a custom head symbol that has the `Orderless` attribute, and if formatting really matters you could use the various formatting techniques that have recently been discussed here =)