# Unsort: remembering a permutation and undoing it

Tags: sorting, wolfram-mathematica, permutation

Suppose I have a function f that takes a vector v and returns a new vector with the elements transformed in some way.
It does that by calling function g that assumes the vector is sorted.
So I want f to be defined like so:

```
f[v_] := Module[{s, r},
  s = Sort[v];  (* remember the permutation applied in order to sort v *)
  r = g[s];
  Unsort[r]     (* apply the inverse of that permutation *)
]
```

What's the best way to do the "Unsort"?

Or could we get really fancy and have this somehow work:

```
answer = Unsort[g[Sort[v]]];
```

ADDED: Let's make this concrete with a toy example.
Suppose we want a function f that takes a vector and transforms it by adding to each element the next smallest element, if any.
That's easy to write if we assume the vector is sorted, so let's write a helper function g that makes that assumption:

```
g[v_] := v + Prepend[Most@v, 0]
```

Now for the function we really want, f, that works whether or not v is sorted:

```
f[v_] := (* remember the order; 
            sort it;
            call g on it;
            put it back in the original order;
            return it
         *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to TomD and Yaroslav, here's probably the most concise/elegant way to do it:

```
f[v_] := g[Sort@v][[Ordering@Ordering@v]]
```

And thanks to Janus, here's a perhaps more efficient way:

```
f[v_] := With[{o = Ordering@v}, g[v[[o]]][[Ordering@o]]]
```

Note that it does 2 sorts instead of 3.

For posterity, here's my original attempt, though I don't think it has anything to recommend it over the above:

```
f[v_] := With[{o = Ordering[v]}, Sort[Transpose[{o,g[v[[o]]]}]][[All,-1]]]
```

To address belisarius in the comments, the reason I'm not passing g as a parameter is because I'm thinking of g as a helper function for f.
It's like I have a function f that would be easier to write if I could assume its argument was a sorted vector.
So I write the version that assumes that and then do this wrapper trick.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to pass **g** as a parameter.

Comment: or slightly more efficient, change your original to `With[{o = Ordering[v]}, Part[g[v[[o]]]],Ordering[o]]]`.

Answer (score 6):

One possible method:

```
 mylist = {c, 1, a, b, 2, 4, h, \[Pi]}
    g /@ (Sort@mylist)[[Ordering@Ordering@mylist]]
```

gives

{g[c], g[1](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00920.html), g[a], g[b], g[2], g[4], g[h], g[[Pi]]}

That is,

```
(Sort@mylist)[[Ordering@Ordering@mylist]] == mylist
```

I originally learned of the above from MathGroup, [EDITED] from a post by Andrzej Kozlowski

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00920.html

Comment: Ordering^(2n) === Ordering^2 ; Ordering^(2n+1) === Ordering :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "sorting wrapper" pattern [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189895/patterns-with-orderless-subexpressions/4201903#4201903) by Michael Pilat earlier

```
Clear[g];
g[a_] := If[OrderedQ[a], a^2, Print["Failed"]];
g[{3, 2, 1}]
g[a_] := g[Sort@a][[Ordering@Ordering@a]] /; Not[OrderedQ[a]];
g[{3, 2, 1}]
```

Comment: This confused me at first, I think because we weren't quite on the same page about what the function g is.  See the update to my answer.  But, wait, I guess what you're doing here is obviating the need for a separate helper function (what I called g) by having two versions of f.  Smart!  I think this would be less confusing if you got rid of the g here though.