# Ordering@Ordering and Ranking Permutations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

As pointed out by nazdrovje (see [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00931.html)) `Ordering@Ordering` may be used to obtain the rank of each element in a list.  Even when the list contains repeated elements the result is an *n*-permutation (taken as an ordered list of integers 1 to n without repetition), where the lowest ranked element is assigned 1, the second lowest 2, etc. As pointed out by [Andrzej Kozlowski](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00920.html), the following holds (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545223/unsort-remembering-a-permutation-and-undoing-it/4547546#4547546)):

```
(Sort@mylist)[[Ordering@Ordering@mylist]]==mylist
```

I'd like to produce a ranking permutation where the *highest* ranked element is assigned 1, the second *highest* 2, etc. such that the following holds:

```
(Reverse@Sort@mylist)[[newPermutation]]==mylist
```

This seems simple, but I have only been able to come up with quite an awkward solution.  At the moment I do the following:

```
newPermutation= Ordering@Ordering[Ordering@Ordering@mylist,All,Greater]
```

Is there a more elegant,or more intuitive, way?  There surely must be?

An example:

```
mylist= {\[Pi],"abc",40,1, 300, 3.2,1};

Ordering@Ordering@mylist

Ordering@Ordering[Ordering@Ordering@mylist,All,Greater]
```

Output (note the reciprocal relationship between the permutations)

```
{7,6,4,1,5,3,2}
{1,2,4,7,3,5,6}
```

(Both the following evaluate to True)

```
Sort@mylist)[[Ordering@Ordering@mylist]]== mylist
Reverse@Sort@mylist)[[ Ordering@Ordering[Ordering@Ordering@mylist,All,Greater]]]== mylist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set

```
 oldPerm = Ordering@Ordering@mylist
```

then

```
 newPerm = - oldPerm + Length@mylist + 1
```

and

```
(Reverse@Sort@mylist)[[newPerm]]==mylist
```

is 
    `True`

---

**So, you may define**

```
newPerm[x_] := 1 + Length@x - Ordering@Ordering@x
```

Such as

```
(Reverse@Sort@mylist)[[newPerm[mylist]]] == mylist
```

is `True`

Comment: That is very nice!  Thank you.  I was debating whether or not to post the question as I did have a solution of sorts.  I am very glad I did now.

Comment: @TomD In Mma _there is always another way_, and sometimes one just can't find the easiest. The community here is very helpful with this kind of problems. Glad to help!