# sorting with changes to the other part in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, list-manipulation

I am just wondering:

given a list `{{{3,1,2},{4,2,5}},{{7,1},{2,4}}}`, I want to sort the first component, then have the second component change as the first one does. The desired result is `{{{1,2,3},{2,5,4}},{{1,7},{4,2}}}`.

How can I do this? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
#[[ All, Ordering@#[[1]] ]] & /@ list
```

---

This is shorter than Michael's, and nearly twice as efficient.

```
micSort = {#[[Ordering[#]]], #2[[Ordering[#]]]} & @@@ # &;

wizSort = #[[All, Ordering@#[[1]]]] & /@ # &;

a = RandomInteger[100, {2400, 2, 15}];

micSort@a === wizSort@a
First@Timing@Do[#@a, {25}] & /@ {micSort, wizSort}

Out[1]= True

Out[2]= {0.453, 0.282}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's the job-security-ensuring one-liner =)

```
In[16]:= list={{{3,1,2},{4,2,5}},{{7,1},{2,4}}};

In[17]:= {#[[Ordering[#]]],#2[[Ordering[#]]]}& @@@ list
Out[17]= {{{1,2,3},{2,5,4}},{{1,7},{4,2}}}
```

This might be a little more clear as to what's happening:

```
sorter[{a_, b_}] :=
 Module[{order = Ordering[a]},
  {a[[order]], b[[order]]}
  ]

In[19]:= sorter /@ list

Out[19]= {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 4}}, {{1, 7}, {4, 2}}}
```

Comment: I like `Ordering`, it's a very useful function. But it's a brain teaser sometimes. Do you know what `ListOfNumbers //Ordering //Ordering` does?

Comment: It gives the permutation that, if applied to the sorted ListOfNumber, will give back the original list.

Comment: @Sasha Yeah, that's the boring way to describe it ;-) However, there is more useful way of looking at the result. Any idea?

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries.  It gives the rank of an element in a list. This has been discussed [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00931.html).  As Andrzej Kozlowski has pointed out, (Sort@mylist)[[Ordering@Ordering@mylist]] == mylist
( see [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00920.html)).  You may be interested in this SO question by dreeves ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545223/unsort-remembering-a-permutation-and-undoing-it))

Comment: @TomD I know that thread as I started it (under my gamer's tag)... ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries In that case I have learned a lot from you in the past. I have found that particular thread very useful. :-)